# Why doesn't `Range#cover?` raise an exception when comparison fails?

Tags: ruby, casting, comparison, range, coerce

Given that `Time` objects cannot be compared with `Fixnum` without explicit casting:

```
0 <= Time.now # => ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with Time failed
Time.now <= 10000000000 # => ArgumentError: comparison of Time with 10000000000 failed
```

and what the [documentation for `Range#cover?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) says,

> `cover?(obj)` → `true` or `false`
>
> Returns `true` if `obj` is between the `begin` and `end` of the range.
>
> This tests `begin <= obj <= end` when `exclude_end?` is `false` and `begin <= obj < end` when `exclude_end?` is `true`.

I expect:

```
(0...10000000000).cover?(Time.now) # => false
```

to raise an exception rather than silently return `false`. Why doesn't it raise an exception?

It is understandable that, with explicit casting, the comparison works:

```
(0...10000000000).cover?(Time.now.to_i) # => true
```

Comment: `range_cover` uses `r_less` and r_less returns a positive value for non-comparable things: https://github.com/stulentsev/ruby/blob/62b750bb55916e526fb53cb4c19da777872c27f6/range.c#L174-L187

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am not that good in reading Ruby C-code. Does it mean that the doc is wrong? Can you elaborate that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc doesn't mention an implementation detail. [`range_cover`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3ad8210ce18ebc926feaf300ab0f93c171329078/range.c#L1192-L1200) is implemented in terms of `r_less` (via `r_cover_p`). And [`r_less`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3ad8210ce18ebc926feaf300ab0f93c171329078/range.c#L174-L187) comment says:

```
/* compares _a_ and _b_ and returns:
 * < 0: a < b
 * = 0: a = b
 * > 0: a > b or non-comparable
 */
```

Here is the source of `r_cover_p`:

```
static VALUE
r_cover_p(VALUE range, VALUE beg, VALUE end, VALUE val)
{
  if (r_less(beg, val) <= 0) {
    int excl = EXCL(range);
    if (r_less(val, end) <= -excl)
      return Qtrue;
  }
  return Qfalse;
}
```

As we can see, a positive number returned from either of `r_less` invocations will result in a `Qfalse`.

Now, the reason why the doc doesn't mention it, I think, is to keep it light. Normally (99.9999% of cases), you're supposed to compare comparable things, right? And in the odd case you don't, you still get a correct answer ("this Time does not belong to this range of integers").

Comment: "this Time does not belong to this range of integers" is what I expect for `include?`. I think the purpose for the method `cover?` to exist is to describe something different from it, namely that an element is **in between** the both ends, which for incomparable things, should be undefined.

Comment: @sawa: maybe they'll fix it someday :)

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit more efficient than just waiting for the fix.

Comment: jfyi, you have misspelled the method name in the ticket title.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure both .include? and .cover? uses the case quality operator (`===`) so the value you get is the same as:

```
p Time.now === 1000 #=> false
```

Comment: I see. Then it looks like a documentation bug, at least. But does that mean `Range#include?` and `Range#cover?` are the same? I suppose not.

Comment: According to "The Ruby Programming language book", `Range#cover?` in v1.9 same as `Range#include?` in 1.8. In 1.9 they are different.

Comment: `cover?`, unlike `include?` doesn't use any equality operators. This is its strength: O(1) runtime.